# Chrome won't find a long local file path for a json file while windows explorer finds it

Tags: java, google-chrome, path, automated-tests, explorer

I have this file

```
file:///D:/arie/git/test_tool3/test_automation/baselines/folder1/folder3.2.1.85.49/3c476e5f494fb944905bc4636c6f29c7af207cbfed999c54b47a26964392d2ce/06-30-2018/B/Folder3Something/Folder_folder3D-324jkhdfs83jhfds8324jhsdf8s9324jklhsdfkjh324-2.5.json
```

When I try to open it from within chrome, chrome comes up with a message

```
Your file was not found It may have been moved or deleted.
```

ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

However if I open the same file from within windows explorer, it finds the file and launches a text editor to open it.

lastly if I copy the file to D:\ and try to open it from within chrome, chrome finds the path of the file successfully.

My question is : What is wrong with the path to the file? 
I tried fetching the absolute path from within bash and compare it to the path that shows up in chrome, but there was no difference (same caps,characters etc)

Answer (score 1):

Well, nobody will ever need such a long JSON file name. So you have 2 options here:

1. Save the JSON file in a direct folder, and not going into more and more folders.
2. Try to shorten your JSON file name as possible. Encode this long string or remove parts that you don't need.